# CSRF token is always invalid in Symfony forms if I use custom token authenticator and stateless is set to false

Tags: symfony, csrf

security.yaml

```yaml
security:
  providers:
    my_user_provider:
      id: CustomUserProvider
  firewalls:
    main:
      provider: my_user_provider
      stateless: false
      custom_authenticators:
         authenticators: CustomAuthTokenAuthenticator
```

framework.yaml

```yaml
framework:
  csrf_protection: true  
  session:
    handler_id: null
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
    storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native
```

**Scenario 1** - user is not authenticated

No problems with csrf tokens in all forms.

**Scenario 2** - user is authenticated and `stateless` is set to `true`

No problems with csrf tokens in all forms.

**Scenario 3** - user is authenticated and `stateless` is set to `false`

After submitting each form on the site there is an error that my CSRF token is invalid.

---

How can I keep csrf tokens enabled and working with `stateless` option set to `false`?

I tested it on SF 6.x and 5.x